# Java RMI ServerException - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.prog.rmi.RmiServer_Stub

Tags: java, rmi

I have inherited some Java RMI client/server code, and while it runs fine on one machine, I haven't been able to get it to run in my dev environment.

The problem is when I run the server using the following `java.exe -Djava.security.policy=conf\server.policy -SRC;. -Djava.library.path=. org.prog.rmi.RmiServer`

I get the following error:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.prog.rmi.RmiServer_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:396)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    ...
```

My `server.policy` file is

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

And my java code:

```
        package org.prog.rmi;

        import java.rmi.Naming;
        import java.rmi.RemoteException;
        import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
        import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
        import java.rmi.registry.*; 

        public class RmiServer extends UnicastRemoteObject 
            implements RmiServerIntf {

        private BatchApi bapi;
        private String iniFileLocation;
        private String layoutOption;
        private int addressCount = 0;
        private RefInt apiHandle = new RefInt();


        public RmiServer(String iniFileLocation,String layoutOption) throws RemoteException 
        {   super();
            this.iniFileLocation = iniFileLocation;
            this.layoutOption = layoutOption;
            initAPI();
            startupAPI();
            openAPI();      
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) 
        {
            System.out.println("RMI server started");

            // Create and install a security manager
            if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) 
            {
                System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
                System.out.println("Security manager installed.");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Security manager already exists.");

            try  //special exception handler for registry creation
            {
                LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099); 
                System.out.println("java RMI registry created.");
            }
            catch (RemoteException e)
            {
                //do nothing, error means registry already exists
                System.out.println("java RMI registry already exists.");
            }

            try
            {
                //Instantiate RmiServer
                for (String arg: args){
                    System.out.println(arg);
                }

                RmiServer obj = new RmiServer(args[0],args[1]);

                // Bind this object instance to the name "RmiServer"
                Naming.rebind("//127.0.0.1/RmiServer", obj);
                System.out.println("PeerServer bound in registry");

            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.err.println("RMI server exception:");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }    
}
```

I've seen solutions relating to the `java.rmi.server.codebase` but didn't have any luck setting this either

Comment: Shouldn't you bind your server to "rmi://localhost:1099/RmiServer"? Your URL does not seem correctly written. I am not certain that this is the cause of the problem, but fixing this would be a good start.

Comment: This sounds tricky, I inherited some RMI code myself, but have not had much trouble running it. One thing we do is package our compiled jar with both the client and server. Which at least assures all the same internal class definitions are available.

Comment: Also, are you sure to be using JDK 1.5 or superior when running the code outside your development environment? I believe the feature to autogenerate proxies was provided in JDK 1.5 and only for servers extending UnicastRemoteObject, otherwise you would be force to rmic your server and generate stubs yourself.

Comment: Hi edalorzo, I didn't write the code, so don't know how the URL should be formatted, but a quick Google provides similar examples e.g. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/getstart.doc.html e.g. Naming.rebind("//myhost/HelloServer", obj); I will try changing the URL as you suggest and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Hi gnomed, how would I go about doing this - currently, I'm trying to get the client and server running on the same machine and both the client and server files are in the same directory. Should I compile them all into the same JAR? or separate ones?

Comment: edalarzo - regarding your second comment - All servers are using at least JRE 1.6 with minor differences in point versions. The development server doesn't actually have the JDK on as I'm just trying to use compiled class files from the two working servers.

Comment: @edalorzo the feature works for any JRMP remote object provided a port number is specified when exporting it.

Comment: I will never understand how people skip over the actual exception and its message and only focus on the 'no security manager' part. The *actual* problem here is a ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation and following RMI tutorials it appeared that there was a problem with the RMI registration server on port 1099.

When I stared the RMI registration server on another port (e.g. 2005) and changed these lines of code

```
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2005);
```

and

```
Naming.rebind("//127.0.0.1:2055/RmiServer", obj);
```

This ran sucessfully without errors and my client was able to connect.

I hope this answer helps others with this error. Let me know if anyone needs any more detailed information.

Comment: Just changing the port number wouldn't fix that. I suspect creating it on 1099 was silently failing because there was already another Registry running without the stub in its class path, and because the exception was suppressed or ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't regenerated the stub with *rmic*, or the Registry doesn't have access to it via its classpath.

Comment: Hi EJP, would you be able to provide some additional explaination? Do I need to regenerate the stub file when the RMI server program is moved to another machine - can I not just copy the stub file across? I've just tried regenerating it with the code rmic org.prog.rmi.RmiServer and this doesn't seem to have made a difference. I'm not sure what you mean by "the registry doesn't have access to it via it's classpath" - what do I need to do here?

Comment: @Loftx It's a compilation step, it's not dependent on which machine. You can copy it around. You need to either start the Registry in the server JVM (recommended) via LocateRegistry, or start *rmiregistry* with -J-Dclasspath= whatever JAR files are required.